# How to query CRM Dynamics entities using raw TSQL only instead of Web API and Org Service?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'm helping migrate my company from CRM 2011 to CRM Dynamics online. Many of the applications we use currently run TSQL in order to obtain entities. Is it possible to execute TSQL against this latest new version of Microsoft CRM in order to obtain entities? Am I limited in using the Web API and Org service in order to obtain entities or is there some way for me to execute raw TSQL?

I'd like to have the option to use TSQL if possible. I understand the Web API service is the latest approach to obtaining entities using a REST API. However, I don't want to be limited to this. Is this possible?

Comment: do you have followup questions?

Comment: @ArunVinoth, Thank you for asking. At this point I dont have any more questions. All this information was very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For real-time connections you are bound to the Web API (OData) endpoint. The documentation for the Web API endpoint can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/use-microsoft-dynamics-365-web-api). It is not possible to directly connect to the Dynamics 365 database.

You can use the Data Export Service to replicate your data in Dynamics 365 to an Azure SQL database. The documentation for the Data Export Service can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/replicate-data-microsoft-azure-sql-database). The Data Export Service replication happens near real-time. However, the name of the tables and columns won't be exactly the same as they were in the Filtered Views, so changes to your current SQL scripts will be inevitable to get your setup working again.

Answer (score 1):

TSQL - Strictly No. Actually, its Impossible to get SQL access for CRM Online.

Hence you are limited with Web API or SDK service call. However if you want to do SQL replication to on-premise or Azure IaaS server using Scribe or Data export service, then you can stay with T-SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

TSQL access to the CDS and D365 should now be possible as MS has just announced a TSQL end point for CDS. You can execute SQL against entities, like the example below, on Dynamics but in read only though.

```
select top 5 a.name as [VIP customer], a.address1_postalcode as [ZIP code] from account a order by a.address1_postalcode desc
```

The link below from MS describes how to set this up in SSMS,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/cds-sql-query

Also, the following link is a very useful blog on getting it up and running, you may have to update EnableTDSEndpoint tag to true manually within the orgdborgsettings field in the organization entity.

https://markcarrington.dev/2020/05/13/cds-t-sql-endpoint-pt-1-connecting/

Credit to Mark Carrington

Comment: Link an answer is welcomed, but please provide [some context](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), so the questioners and others could provide from your solution.

Comment: Any way to enable full permissions to execute CRUD sql queries for dynamics CRM online? I'm using SQL views in my on-premise setup and I can't find a way to replicate those with the provided web-api. I'm not sure if it would be wise to use the web-api for simple update/create/delete request and use SQL to query data with read-only to achieve the behavior as my views, but without views...